# Are any solutions lost when solving non-exact differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have just started studying differential equations, one of the problems I found while I was practicing is "Consider the equation 
$$ (y^2 + 2xy)dx - x^2 dy=0  $$
(a) Show that this equation is not exact.
(b) Show that multiplying both sides of the equation by $$ 1/y^2 $$ yields a new equation that is exact.
(c) Use the solution of the resulting exact equation to solve the original equation.
(d) Were any solutions lost in the process?

I've worked it out and found that the general solution is:
$$ y= x^2 / c-x $$

What I don't understand is (d). What is meant by "Any solutions lost in the process"? How would a solution be lost, and why? And what am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Compare it to an equation in polynomials $$x^2+2x=3x-x^2$$ Dividing by $x$, we get the solution $x+2=3-x\implies x=0.5$, but we "lost" the solution $x=0$.

Comment: Is anything along the same lines happening here? You "lost" $y=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how did you get that equation of polynomials?

Comment: It was a random example for the sake of demonstration, to show what "losing" a solution usually means. My point is, check that $y=0$ satisfies the original differential equation.

Comment: Thanks, but uh... I don't think I got it. Could you tell me more?

Comment: How do you think they got $1/y^2$?

Comment: @Zushauque when you multiply by $1/y^2$ you implicitly remove $y=0$ from consideration. You need to check these edge cases separately. For my original example, multiplying by $1/x$ removes $x=0$ from consideration.

Comment: the function $y=0$ satisfies the equation but not contained in the ''general'' solutioun. Such solutions are called singular solutions.

Comment: @Mhenni by a special integrating factor, I assume. Where $$ \mu(x) = \exp{(dM/dY-dN/dx) /N dx} $$

Comment: @Sabyasachi Oh, I got it. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @Zushauque you're welcome. :)

Comment: @Zushauque: You are welcome.